# How can I draw this picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

How can I draw the picture below? Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! That sounds like a DO-IT-for me question. Please add some working code.

Comment: The title mentions two figures, but only one is shown. Le titre mentionne deux figures, mais une seule est montrée.

Comment: @egreg [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436793/121799) is why. (But I also was confused about the fact that the "two" was "lost in translation". ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}%
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
draw,rounded corners,inner sep=8pt,
edge=<->,
s sep=9mm,
l sep=7mm}
 [112,label=above:{\'e}tat max
  [111
   [110
    [100,name=100]
    [,phantom
     [000,name=000,label=below:{\'e}tat min]
    ]   
    [010,name=010] 
   ]
  ]
 ] 
\draw[<->] (100) -- (000);
\draw[<->] (010) -- (000);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One could use `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt, svgnames]{standalone}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-arrow}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % to compile with pdflatex --enable-write18 (MiKTeX) or pdflatex -shell-escape (TeX Line, MacTeX)
\newpsobject{frameaux}{psframebox}{linecolor=IndianRed, framesep=6pt, framearc=0.2}
\newcommand\myframe[2]{\psDefBoxNodes{#1}{\frameaux{\,#2\,}}}

\begin{document}

\psset{linejoin =1}
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0.2cm, rowsep=0.5cm]
 & \myframe{a}{112} \\
 & \myframe{b}{111} \\
 & \myframe{c}{110} \\
\myframe{d}{100} & &\myframe{e}{010} \\
 & \myframe{f}{000}
 \psset{arrows=v-v, veearrowlength=1.5mm, veearrowlinewidth=0.8pt, linecolor=LightSlateGrey}
 \nput[labelsep =4pt]{90}{a:tC}{état max}\nput[labelsep =3pt]{-90}{f:bC}{état min}
 \ncline{a:bC}{b:tC}
 \ncline{b:bC}{c:tC}
 \ncline{c:Cl}{d:tC}
 \ncline{c:Cr}{e:tC}
 \ncline{d:bC}{f:Cl}
 \ncline{e:bC}{f:Cr}
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]